# To show that a matrix defines a map from $l^2$ to $l^2$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

Let $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{4} \dots\\
0 &\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{4} \dots\\
0 & 0 &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots &\dots
\end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find out if this matrix defines a map from $l^2$ to $l^2$. For that I look at a typical $y(j)$ position, meaning if I multiply $M$ by $x=\left(x(1),x(2),..,x(j),...\right)$, I get $y=\left(y(1),y(2),..,y(j),..\right)$ and for $M$ to be a map each $y(j)$ should make sense and whole of $y$ should make sense.

For each $y(j)$ to make sense , $y(j)=\sum_{k=j}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k}x(k)$, should converge. So I look at $$\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{k} x(k)| \le \sqrt{\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}} \times ||x||_2$$
So the series converges absolutely and hence it converges. No problem with this.

Now $y$ should be in $l^2$ for everything to fall through. So I look at $$||y||^{2}_2=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}x(k)\right)|^2 \le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{k}x(k)|\right)^2 $$
$$\le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\{\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}|x(k)|^2\right)\} $$

This is where I am stuck . I can always pull out $||x||_2$ but that doesn't help. I have a double series here. To solve this problem it seems to me that i have to show that this is double series converges. Cauchy-Schwarz is the best possible approximation I can get. So I don't think I have to do something with that.

I tried to use the fact that the tail of the series goes to zero but that doesn't help either. (since there is a difference between going to zero and actually being zero)

Now suppose I multiply the matrix with $ x=(0,...0, j,0,0,0..) $ where $ j $ is at the $ k$ th place, then $ y=(1,1,1,...,1,0,0..0) $ where the last$1$ is at the $ k $ th place. Also $||y||_2=\sqrt {k}$.

This doesn't lead to anything.  I think that finally it boils down to choosing $ x $ such that the series on the right diverges.

Suppose I multiply by an arbitrary $x=\left(x(1),x(2),..,x(j),..\dots \right)$, (of course $x \in l^2$)then $y=(y(1),y(2),..,y(j),..\dots )$, where $y(j)=\sum_{k=j}^{\infty} \dfrac{x(k)}{k}$.

I am unable to find an $x$. 
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Your upper bound is definitely too generous to show convergence; $\sum_{k=j}^{\infty} 1/k^2 \approx \frac{1}{j}$, so it's not too hard to pick $x$ so that the tail converges too slowly for the double sum to converge; e.g. choose $x$ so that $\sum_{k=j}^\infty |x(k)|^2 = \frac{1}{\log j}$.

Comment: choosing $x(j)$ is not in my hands, It needs to work for any $x$.

Comment: And if it doesn't work for a chosen $x$, then it can't possibly work for all $x$.

Comment: oh.. you are disproving it. I thought of it for a moment. The inequalities won't work then. I see.

Comment: I have to find out an $x$.

Comment: @hurkyl you want ne to use the series $\frac {1}{log n}$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove this, it seems to me that one could follow the proof of the *Schur test* (e.g., Exercise 9 in II.1 of "A course on functional analysis" by Conway or Problem 45 in "A Hilbert space problem book" by Halmos).

I guess it could be summarized as follows (in loose terms). The sequence we are interested in is

$$ y_i=\sum_{j=i}^\infty\frac{1}{j}x_j $$

where $x$ has finite $l^2$-norm. One has

$$
\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\lvert y_i\rvert^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\left\lvert\sum_{j=i}^\infty \frac{1}{j}x_j \right\rvert^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\left\lvert\sum_{j=i}^\infty \frac{1}{j^{3/4}}\frac{x_j}{j^{1/4}} \right\rvert^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\left(\sum_{j=i}^\infty\frac{1}{j^{3/2}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=i}^\infty\frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{j^{1/2}}\right)\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\frac{\alpha}{i^{1/2}}\left(\sum_{j=i}^\infty\frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{j^{1/2}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Here, the last inequality follows from the fact that the first sum over $j$ can be majorized by $\alpha/i^{1/2}$ for suitable $\alpha>0$. Now, we can interchange the order of summation in the $i$-$j$ plane to get

$$
\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert^2\leq\sum_{j=1}^\infty\,\sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{\alpha}{i^{1/2}}\frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{j^{1/2}}
=
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\,\frac{\lvert x_j\rvert^2}{j^{1/2}}\sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{\alpha}{i^{1/2}}
\end{align}
$$

However, one can find $\beta>0$ such that $j^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^{j}i^{-1/2}\leq\beta$. In total, we thus obtain

$$
\lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert^2\leq\alpha\beta\,\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert^2
$$

Note: **Schur test** (from Conway's book)

Let $\{\alpha_{i,j}\}_{i,j=1}^\infty$ be an infinite matrix such that $\alpha_{i,j}\geq0$ for all $i,j$ and such that there are scalars $p_i>0$ and $\beta,\gamma>0$ with

$$\sum_i \alpha_{i,j}p_i\leq \beta\,p_j $$ and $$\sum_j \alpha_{i,j}p_j\leq \gamma\,p_i $$

for all $i,j\geq1$. Then there is an operator $A$ on $l^2(\mathcal{N})$ with $\langle e_i\vert A e_j\rangle = \alpha_{i,j}$ and $\lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert^2\leq \beta\gamma$.

Comment: What is schur test??

Comment: How do you find a $\beta$ such that this happens: "  one can find $β>0$ such that $j^{−1/2}\sum_{i=1}^{j}\dfrac{\alpha}{i^{−1/2}}≤β"$??

Comment: the idea was that in order to estimate the sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^{j}i^{-1/2}$, one can consider the definite integral $\int_0^y1/\sqrt{x}\text{d}x=2\sqrt{y}$. Then $S=1^{-1/2}\times1+2^{-1/2}\times1+\ldots$ can be interpreted as lower-bound estimate for the integral, thus $S\leq2j^{1/2}$

Comment: you are suggesting that i integrate from $1$ to $j$. Nice. Thanks.

Comment: How did you majorize $\sum_{j=i}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ by $\frac{\alpha}{i^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ for each $i$??

Comment: in loose terms, $\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}1/j^{3/2}$ should be majorized by, e.g., $\int_{i}^{\infty}4/x^{3/2}\text{d}x=8/\sqrt{i}$, since $4/(j+1)^{3/2}\geq1/j^{3/2}$ and thus each rectangle with left bottom corner $(j,0)$ and top left corner at $(j+1, j^{3/2})$ is fully "under" the curve $y=4/x^{3/2}$